# Как использовать memcache и apc в одном проекте?

Tags: кэширование, memcached, php

Приведите простой пример что, где и как кешировать?

Answer (score 1):

Кешировать следует то - что выполняется долго или требует много вычислительных ресурсов, например изменение размеров изображений, долгие запросы в базу и тд. Существует много систем кеширования. Использовать memcache и apc одновременно можно, но следует помнить что и ресурсы будут они кушать вместе. Ставите пакеты php5-memcache php-apc и используете, для каждого из них предусмотрены соответствующие функции и классы.

[memcache](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/book.memcache.php)

[apc](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/book.apc.php)